# Variable with same name inside function changes the value of the passed parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a javascript function as below :

```js
function modifyx(xvalue) {
  val = 1;
  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    val = val + 1;
  }
  return val;
}
```

And the main snippet passes a variable named x to the above function as below:

```js
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log(modifyx(x));
}
```

The expected output should be "11" printed 10 times but instead it prints one time. The function call changes the value of x eventhough i am not modifying the passed value. The x inside the function has it's own scope. Yet it gets modified. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing `x` in the function call, you never use `xvalue` in `modifyx()`

Comment: This is just an example. Actually i am using the value as a "readonly" inside my function. The question is why this is happening?

Comment: I'm simply trying to get a better understanding of what you wish to accomplish but I understand your question better now. You simply want to know **why** you are getting the output.

Comment: You're declaring `x` as an implicit global... they refer to the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `x` in your code is `global`. When your method `modifyx(xvalue)` returns for the first time the value of `x` is already 11 which is used in the for loop for the second iteration. Thus it fails to execute the method further.

Use `let x` in the declaration in `for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)` to create a unique execution environment.

```js
function modifyx(xvalue) {
  val = 1;
  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    val = val + 1;
  }
  return val;
}

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log(modifyx(x));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was actually freaking out and didn't realize this small mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Just put var in both places in for loop

```
function modifyx(xvalue) {
  val = 1;
  for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    val = val + 1;
  }
  return val;
}

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  console.log(modifyx(x));
}
```

because its taking x as global variable in your code.

Comment: I explained in the last line right.It is taking x as global variable.So x inside inner function loops for ten times and the loop outside the function terminates,because the value of x reaches 10 because it is the same x.

Answer (score 0):

MDSN documentation on variable scopes in JavaScript:

> JavaScript has two scopes: global and local. A variable that is
>   declared outside a function definition is a global variable, and its
>   value is accessible and modifiable throughout your program. A variable
>   that is declared inside a function definition is local. It is created
>   and destroyed every time the function is executed

---

When using the `var` keyword, the variable declaration is pulled to the top of it's scope (the function).

In your example code, you are using a for loop **without** defining `var x`. When you use `for (x = 0...`, the browser assumes you meant `for (var x = 0...` so it creates a global variable called x.

Inside your function `modifyx`, you are setting the **global** `x` to 11 by the end of it's execution. This causes the outer loop to run only once because x is no longer less than 10 after the first loop.

---

Here is an example of what's going on with comments:

```
function modifyx(xvalue) {
    val = 1;
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { // sets the global 'x' to 11 after loop finishes
        val = val + 1;
    }
    return val;
}

// 'x' is being defined as a global variable
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log(modifyx(x)); // modifyx sets 'x' to 11
    // x is now 11, loop will now quit
}
```

---

A simple solution is to use the `let` keyword in both loops, thus restricting the scope.

```
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) { ... }
```